# composer change cache directory

Tags: php, composer-php

But default composer install this cache in my directory shop/cache

I would know if it's possible to change this directory to another /Shop/Core/Work/Composer/ for example

Is it this function ?

```
putenv('COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=' . static::$root . '/Shop/Core/Work/Composer/');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [configuration](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#cache-dir) for that.

You can also try changing the [COMPOSER_HOME](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home) environment variable.

Comment: if you are executing composer using sudo -u <user>, you need set the COMPOSER_HOME after sudo. For example: sudo COMPOSER_HOME=<path_to_composer_home> -u www-data composer require xxxxxx

Answer (score 2):

You can set the cache directory in your composer.json project using cache-dir:

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "cache-dir": "./.cache",
    "platform": {
        "php": "8.1.0"
    }
}
```