# Running composer installation in a Symfony 3.2 project on a machine that shares 2 environments

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.1

I have in the same server in 2 differents directories, like this:

- /var/www/pre.myproject.com/
- /var/www/myproject.com/

**pre.myproject.com** is a full copy from production **myproject.com**

When I am trying to run the command composer install inside the folder **/var/www/pre.myproject.com/** with this:

```
 composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader
```

I see the following errors:

```
Cannot create cache directory /var/www/myproject.com/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /var/www/myproject.com/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable.Proceeding without cache
```

Why is it trying to make changes in myproject.com if I am currently at pre.myproject.com?

What files should I change in my folder **pre.myproject.com** to **enable a new environment in Symfony3**? And so the composer can install correctly for this environment and within this directory?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where is the Composer binary located?

Comment: What you should do is not ``composer install`` but ``composer update`` as the composer.json file should already exist, it'll just read it and download the dependencies packages

Comment: @vincentPHILIPPE why should one do that? `composer update` will update the dependencies, and as far as this is not explicitly what the OP wants to do, this could cause more problems

Comment: @NicoHaase He want a full copy from production. ``composer update`` will just read the existing ``composer.json`` and install the dependencies? Why do you think it could cause some problems ?

Comment: `composer update` will **update** the dependencies, that's why it's called `update`

Comment: Also, this does not resolve the question why these commands use a different folder

Answer (score 0):

This question was not answered so far:

> Why is it trying to make changes in myproject.com [...]?

The changes are with the path from the error message:

```
/var/www/myproject.com/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/
```

Composer has a parameter for this path and that is the *composer cache directory*. In your case it is configured to point to the following base path:

```
/var/www/myproject.com/.composer/cache
```

It is often based on the `COMPOSER_HOME` parameter, but that is just a detail ([existing Q&A covers this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58323927/367456)).

So use the correct composer configuration for each environment. As with each different environment things can become more demanding, use a build manager to ease the work. It can help you to control all build parameters of the in-tree build.

For your project it seems an in-tree build suffices. In case not, it is of  benefit to make use of a deployment manager as well that takes care to deploy the application out of the project tree.

Answer (score -2):

What you trying to do is having a new installation of an existing Symfony project with an existing `composer.json` file containing all your dependencies.

What you should do is not `composer install` but `composer update` as the composer.json file should already exist, it'll just read it and download the dependencies packages

`composer update` :

> The update command reads the composer.json file from the   current
> directory, processes it, and updates, removes or installs all the
> dependencies.

This is what I am using on my `production` server when I import a new feature from my `development` branch.

---

**Edit**

You should add `--no-cache` option to bypass the cache.

Comment: "updates, removes or installs all the dependencies" - that's not what I would call an exact copy of the production system

Comment: ``composer.json`` already contain the dependencies which should be installed.
Why would he even try to ``composer install`` if he don't want to have a full copy of dependencies ?

Of course, what he's looking for is to get the copy of ``prodcution`` environment, but to make it work, he need to install the dependencies.

Of course also it'll remove the unused dependencies and that's perfectly fine as these dependencies are not in use. This stay an exact copy of the production system as both use the same composer.json file.

Comment: `composer.lock` contains the **resolved** dependencies. To install an **exact** copy of the production system, this should be used. Using `composer update` will install a **different** set of dependencies. Also, how does this resolve the problem that a caching directory from another parent directory is used?

Comment: I guess he just add ``--no-cache`` and he'll be good. But I admit that you're correct. ``composer update`` won't be the solution